# InvalidConfigurationException KernelTestCase

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, phpunit

I’m working on a Symfony project and using the Doctrine ORM.

I installed PhpUnit for Unit Testing.

I tried to test my Application Entities with this:

```
class ApplicationTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    private $application;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();
    }

    public function testApplicationConstruct()
    {
        $this->application = new Application();

        $app = $this->em
            ->getRepository('CEPNPrincipalBundle:Applications')
            ->searchByRoute($this->application->getRoute());
        ;


        $this->assertEquals($app->getRoute(), $this->application->getRoute());
        $this->assertContains('app', $this->application->getRoute());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();

        $this->em->close();
        $this->em = null; // avoid memory leaks
    }
}
```

I get this error when running

```
bin/phpunit --configuration app/config/phpunit.xml.dist 
RuntimeException: Either set KERNEL_DIR in your phpunit.xml according to https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#your-first-functional-test or override the WebTestCase::createKernel() method.
```

I fixed it with this line in phpunit.xml.dist :

```
<php>
    <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="../../app" />
</php>
```

And I got another error:

```
Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException: You are not allowed to define new elements for path "security.firewalls". Please define all elements for this path in one config file
```

Could you help me please?